# Creating geometry field from lat long fields in Geopackage table

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I am playing around with Geopackages for the first time. I've searched hard for valid syntax to generate a geometry field from lat long fields for an attribute-only table in a Geopackage.

The PostGIS method is
alter table a add column geom geometry(Point,4326);
update a set geom = ST_MakePoint(x,y)

I can't get anything similar to work in the SQLite GPK syntax.

Comment: Did you read and try this? http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/new-geom.html

Comment: That old SpatiaLite cookbook does not help much with GeoPackages even they have many common features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind creating a new layer, there are at least two possibilities: using QGIS expressions or using a virtual layer.

1. QGIS expressions: Go to `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Geoemtry by expression`: set your Geopackage (saved without geometry, but containing an attribute for `lat` and `lon`) as input layer, select point as output geometry type and add this expression: `make_point ( "lon" ,  "lat" )`. The created layer is what you're looking for.
2. Create a virtual layer (`Menu Layer / Create Layer / New virtual layer...`) with this query (where temp is the geometry-less Geopackage layer):

```
    select make_point (t.lon, t.lat)
    from temp as t
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I still find it strange that there isn't a native way to do this in the GPKG. But the Spatialite syntax doesn't seem to be working either.